# Block Javascripts in Mozilla for Ads

Tags: javascript, firefox, adblock

This question is related Website browsing. and blocking some ads.

I m using Mozilla firefox and installed "No Scripts" ad block extension. itsb locking all ads that i want. Now i noticed that some website have embed some javascripts in their webpages that detect any extension installed in Browser firefox or Chrome and then REDIRECT to specific custom page which says Please disable your Adblock script/extension.

Like i download files from http://uptobox.com and today it redirect me to an custom html page http://uptobox.com/pages/adblock.html .

Script that do redirect is in this website webpage source.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //alert(document.getElementById("m10i6ekyhkf1").style.height);
    //alert(document.getElementById("m10i6ekyhkf1").clientHeight);
    // Missclick !
    setTimeout(function() {
            if (document.getElementById("m10i6ekyhkf1").clientHeight < 11 || document.getElementById("m10i6ekyhkf1").style.position == "absolue") {
                    document.writeln("Redirection...!");
                    window.location = "/pages/adblock.html";
                    document.getElementById("container-page").innerHTML = '<div class="informations middle-content"><span class="server_name">You are using adblock plus or something else which block advertising!</span><br /><br />Uptobox can only exist today thanks to advertising.<br />Indeed, <b>advertising is one of our biggest income to paid our bandwidth and servers</b>, because our service is mainly free !<br />This is why we ask you to allow ads on Uptobox to use our service !<br />If you haven\'t got an adblocker, you can try to disable your antivirus.<br />(If you have any other issue, please empty your cache and refresh your link)<br /><br />\';<div class="debrid_case"><br /><span class="server_name"><center>Disable adblock</center></span><div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;"><img src="http://uptobox.com/image_default/disableadblock.png" style="border: 5px solid #CFCFCF;" /></div><div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;">You only have to click on "Disable Adblock Plus" <br />or "Disable adblock plus on uptobox.com"</div></div></div>';
            }

            $('.page-top').html($('.page-top').html() + " ");
            $('.file-name').html($('.file-name').html() + " ");


            if ($('.page-top').text().length > 70) {
              var tmp_txt = $('.page-top').html().substr(0, 70);
              $('.page-top').html(tmp_txt);
              $('.page-top').append('...');
            }
    },3000);
  if (window.location.protocol != "http:")
window.location.href = "http:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
```

I want to is there anyway to Stop this script to redirect me or any module/plugin of firefox which stop this javascript by rendering in page in my browser ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a sample download file/page?

Comment: Just google for anti-anti-adblock. Here is an extension for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-anti-adblock/

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out how this script detects adblock.

This code does **not** seem to do extension detection like you suggest. Instead it checks the `.height` of a DOM element. This is probably the element that the ad will get loaded in and if you block the ad scripts the DOM element will not be in the expected state.

You can not detect that a script has not loaded. You can only detect that it's expected effect has not occurred yet. In this case the site waits 3 seconds before it checks. This is a pretty reasonable way to detect generic adblockers, not just adblock plus on Firefox.

---

There is no easy solution to prevent this site from redirecting. Perhaps you can use Greasemonkey to break this code.

One way is to remove the `document.getElementById("m10i6ekyhkf1")` element, that will break the script and prevent the redirect.